# npm cannot load module even though it is installed

Tags: node.js, npm

After patching `repl-plus` package sources to make it run on Linux, I'm running into this:

```
$ repl-plus
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'q'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/bin/repl-plus:9:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
```

However, if I query `npm` for installed packages, I get this:

```
$ npm ls -g | grep q@
| +-- lodash._baseuniq@4.6.0
| +-- lodash.uniq@4.5.0
+-- q@1.5.1
| `-- q@1.5.1
```

Put together unintelligible error message and general low quality of npm-related code... where do I even start trying to solve this problem?